# JasperReports Font adaption when using docx format printing (pdf using correct format)

Tags: jasper-reports, export-to-word

I have a question regarding the font used in pdf and docx formats when printing from a JasperReports jrxml. I followed the instructions defined http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/custom-font-font-extension to get the JasperReports report to print Arial font in both pdf and docx prints. The pdfs happily accepted this and are printing Arial. But no matter what I try, the docx prints always show up as Sans Serif font.

I also already edited the JasperReports property lines as follows:

`net.sf.jasperreports.default.font.name = ArialExtension` (Name of my extension, as created by following the links documentation, jar file)

`net.sf.jasperreports.default.pdf.font.name = ArialExtension`

So, as I understand, JasperReports should always pick Arial as font which it doesn't. I frankly don't know what to do now. We need pdf and docx prints available for our customers and we need them in Arial font.

Can someone point me in another direction or tell me, what I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem! The solution is absolutely not obvious and might not work for everyone. But for me, the correct font was used in DOCX and PDF format when I named my font extension exactly like the font I want to use. So instead of ArialExtension, I called it Arial and my jar was called Arial.jar. Then the font in DOCX was correct, also in PDF.